# git push via nginx reverse proxy stopped working (fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly)

Tags: git, bitbucket, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an issue with my git (Bitbucket). If I try to push a file, which is bigger than 8MB to my git remote, I get the following error message:

> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

> Everything up-to-date

The git remote is behind an Nginx reverse proxy, which has the following config:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name proxy.bitbucket.sample;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://bitbucket.sample:7990;

    proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
    proxy_send_timeout 1800;
    proxy_read_timeout 1800;
    send_timeout 1800;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
}
```

}

The error.log of nginx is empty and the logs on bitbucket has the following message:

```
2020-08-20 10:32:50,672 INFO  [http-scmrequest-handler:thread-1007] sven @U5MKSCx632x20155x0 10.79.1.30,10.79.1.54 "POST /scm/bitsystest/testimport2.git/git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.s.g.p.h.GitSmartExitHandler BITSYSTEST/testimport2[360]: Write request from 10.79.1.30 failed due to a socket timeout
```

This behavior just started a few days ago without any changes to the proxy or to bitbucket.

The only solution I found on the internet was raising the **http.postBuffer**, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same issue. This is a bug i thought. I solved it by downgraded from laste version 7.5.3 to version 7.3.1

Comment: thanks for your comment! thoguht something like this... i guess i will write a ticket then

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug - see https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-12549

Setting plugin.bitbucket-git.hosting.nio.http=false in bitbucket.properties helped (I wonder, what this undocumented option does).